# When finding the derivative of a function why do we have cancel out the x's in the numerator and the denominator?

Tags: derivatives

I get why we cancel them out but I do not understand why we **have** to. Take $x^3+\frac{2}{x^2}$ for example. Why is $3x^2+\frac{2}{2x}$ wrong?

**Note:** Please use terminology that someone just learning about derivatives can understand.

Comment: Your differentiation is wrong regardless of the issue in your question, which is not stated clearly. The derivative of $2/x^2$ is $-4/x^3$. Could you write out where exactly you're "canceling $x$'s"?

Comment: Would you like to explain why the derivative of 2/x^2 is -4/x^3

Comment: Keep in mind that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ can actually be rewritten as $x^{-2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is to assume that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{f'(x)},$$
which is not true. Indeed, you did
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{x^2}=\frac{2}{\frac{d}{dx}x^2}=\frac{2}{2x},$$
which is wrong. The rule for differentiating $1/f(x)$ is rather
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{f(x)}=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}.$$
This follows from the more general rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g'(x)f(x)-g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$
by taking $g(x)=1$.

But even simpler than that, you can get the correct result by writing
$$\frac{2}{x^2}=2x^{-2},$$
and then taking the derivative we get
$$2(-2x^{-3})=-4x^{-3}=-\frac{4}{x^3}.$$